# innodb_page_size is not present in [mysqld] section in my.ini file in MySQL Server 8.0?

Tags: innodb, mysql-8.0, my.ini

I have to edit the innodb_page_size to 32K but I cannot find innodb_page_size in [mysqld] section in my.ini file. I am using MySQL Server 8.0.13. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 1):

If it is not explicitly set it defaults to 16k. You would set it to a new value in the [mysqld] section but it cannot be changed once the instance has been created.